# How to write a "for loop" to calculate statistical information about columns in csv?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I have several datafiles that I need to extract data from and I would like to implement a for loop to do this efficiently. For every data file, I need to calculate the mean and standard deviation for every column. Note that each data file has a different number of rows and columns but the first row always indicates what the column number (see the below illustration). After finding out the mean and standard deviation for each column I would like it to tell me which columns had the largest and smallest mean/standard deviation.

To illustrate here is some data:

```
0           1           2           3
105         154         148         138
74          62          32          178
44          16          156         100
83          19          16          66
```

And here is the desired output

```
Stats for "filename.csv"

           0           1           2           3
Mean       76.5        62.8        88          120.5
Sd         21.9        55.7        64.31       41.8


Smallest Mean - Column "1"
Largest Mean - Column "3
Smallest Sd - Column "0"
Largest Sd - Column "2"
``
```

Comment: Do you have the option to use any libraries i.e `pandas` or should it be implemented from scratch?

Comment: Yes definitely a library from panda or any others in Python would work. I am still learning the basics of python and how to implement for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I have used pandas here.

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
     0    1    2    3
0  105  154  148  138
1   74   62   32  178
2   44   16  156  100
3   83   19   16   66

In [18]: combined = pd.concat([df.mean(), df.std()], axis=1).T

In [19]: combined.index = ["Mean", "Std"]

In [20]: combined
Out[20]:
              0          1          2           3
Mean  76.500000  62.750000  88.000000  120.500000
Std   25.278449  64.360314  74.260802   48.314939
```

In order to get the largest and smallest values:

```
In [40]: print(f'Smallest Mean - Column {combined[combined.index == "Mean"].idxmin(axis=1)[0]}')
Smallest Mean - Column  1

In [41]: print(f'Largest Mean - Column {combined[combined.index == "Mean"].idxmax(axis=1)[0]}')
Largest Mean - Column  3

In [42]: print(f'Largest Std - Column {combined[combined.index == "Std"].idxmax(axis=1)[0]}')
Largest Std - Column  2

In [43]: print(f'Smallest Std - Column {combined[combined.index == "Std"].idxmin(axis=1)[0]}')
Smallest Std - Column 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Array of Mean and Standard Deviation

---

```
import numpy as np  # linear algebra

data = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [105,154, 148, 138],
        [74, 62, 32, 178],
        [44, 16, 156, 100],
        [83, 19, 16, 66]]
data = np.array(data) # transform a list into an numpy array, for best data manipulation
data = data[1:,:] #get all the rows starting from the second (0,1,2,...) so the first is removed
data = data.T #transpose de matrix

mean_std = [ [np.mean(x), np.std(x)] for x in data ]
```

What this code does is

- Data initially is a list, so I call a method from the numpy library via `np.array`which transforms the data into another object, which has some already built-in functions, which I'll be using
- The first row is removed
- The data is transposed because, as you can see in the `data` initialization, it a list of lists, where the second degree list is equivalent of a row. Using `data.T` allows me to  use the next code and apply it column-wise
- This code is more tricky. The statement `for x in data` is the same as do something for each element in `data` (which is the column of your table). This element is saved as `x`. `[np.mean(x), np.std(x)]`. This statement apply the function `np.mean`and `np.std`to each of the `x` elements and saves the result in a list. All this lists of `means`and `std` are saved into another list. Thats the reason for the brackes on the outside of the statement

### Finding Results

---

```
mean = np.array(mean_std).T[0]
std = np.array(mean_std).T[1]
position = np.array(range(0, len(std)))
position[ std == max(std) ]
```

- separates the matrix into two arrays. One of mean and the other of std.
- It creates an array of position
- Uses this array in order to get where is the condition of, in this case max, is satisfied. Which in this case is 2 (third column)